# Operator Monotone

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, operator-theory, monotone-functions

I have two sets $S_1 \subseteq S_2$ and I have a (symmetric-real) positive definite matrix $A$. I would like to know when would the following hold

$$S_1 \subseteq S_2 \Rightarrow A_{S_1} \prec A_{S_2} $$

can this be explained in terms of the Loewner ordering? Do $S_1,S_2$ need to be posets? Thank you.

Comment: What is $A_{S_i}$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy thanks for your reply: suppose that $A$ has the form $A_{S_i} = C + D_{S_i}$ where $C$ is a constant PD matrix and $D_{S_i}$ is also a PD matrix, which is defined as $c_j^Tc_j$ where $c_j$ are row vectors defined in the sets $S_i$. please let me know if it is confusing.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Hi, I was wondering if you could suggest something on this? Would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Are the matrices $A_{S_i}$ defined as $(A_{S_i}u,v)=(Cu,v)+\sum_{c_j\in S_i} (c_j,v)(c_j,u)$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy yes, absolutely.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I am not too sure what the vectors $u,v$ mean here. In my case: $A_{S_i} = C + \sum_{c_j \in S_i} c_j^T c_j$. If what you mentioned is equivalent to this, then, yes! Look forward to hearing from you. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider for a column vector $u$, the operation $(\cdot,\cdot)$ stands for a usual scalar product:
$$(A_{S_1}u,u) = (Cu,u) + \sum_{c_j\in S_1}(c_j^Tc_ju,u) = (Cu,u) + \sum_{c_j\in S_1}|c_ju|^2 \le (Cu,u) + \sum_{c_j\in S_2}|c_ju|^2 = (A_{S_1}u,u).$$
The inequality holds because $S_1\subset S_2$, hence

$$A_{S_1}\le A_{S_2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for this. Does the inequality hold because $A$ is matrix monotone over the sets $S_1,S_2$?